# Kubuntu - Are there 'workspaces' in Kubuntu and how can I switch between them with shortcuts?

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

I used Ubuntu before and now I migrated to Kubuntu. And I'd like to know if there are 'workspaces' in Kubuntu and how I can switch between them with shortcuts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only difference between Ubuntu and Kubuntu is that Ubuntu uses [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) as the [Desktop Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) and Kubuntu uses [KDE](http://www.kde.org/). Linux allows the user to choose which Desktop Environment to use, you can install Unity or Cinnamon or LXDE or whatever you want on your Kubuntu.

That said, yes indeed KDE (which is what you are using) offers workspaces. You should be able to control their behavior by going into the settings app (or running `systemsettings` from a terminal) and then

```
systemsettings -> workspace behavior -> virtual desktops
```

[image]

Comment: What about the keyboard shortcuts for workspaces? I've never been able to figure those out..

Comment: @seth, they should be on the "Switching" tab.

Comment: Where are shortcuts?

Comment: @kangarooo go to system settings. -> shortcuts -> global shortcuts ->  system settings. you can find walk Through desktops and change that shortcuts.

Comment: in Kubuntu 20.04: shortcuts > global shortcuts > Kwin